# rails flash[:notice] after ajax submit, with jquery Timeout misses timeout if page not ready?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an problem regarding a flash :notice which is displayed after an ajax submit.

I have a pop up box to leave a message which is submitted with ajax, after the user clicks submit the pop up box disappears and then the #flash slides out to show the message and then slides back away after.

The problem is that I have a timeout function which allows time for the form to fade away before the flash appears (and also a timeout before the #flash disappears), that all works fine apart from when the page isn't fully loaded the message seems to miss the timeout completely, like if i quickly submit a message when the page appears to be ready the flash will quickly slide out and then be gone before anyone could read it.

This is my code and also I'm new to js:

```
var el = $('#new_message'); //grab the form

setTimeout(showFlashMessages, 800);
setTimeout(hideFlashMessages, 6000);

// this makes the message form disappear
$('#message_pad').animate({'top':'-300px'},500,function(){
  $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
});

//this refreshes the flash partial
$('#flash').html('<%= escape_javascript render( :partial => 'layouts/flash' ) %>');

//this slides out the flash
function showFlashMessages() {
  $('#flash').animate({"top": "+=50px"}, 200)
}

//this hides the flash
function hideFlashMessages() {
  $('#flash').animate({"top": "-=50px"}, 200)
}

// Clear form
el.find('textarea').val('');
```

If there is a better way to do all this some guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange next action when the previous action is done.

```js
var el = $('#new_message'); //grab the form

//this refreshes the flash partial
$('#flash').html('<%= escape_javascript render( :partial => 'layouts/flash' ) %>');

// this makes the message form disappear
$('#message_pad').animate({'top':'-300px'},500,function(){
  $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    setTimeout(showFlashMessages, 800);
  });
});

//this slides out the flash
function showFlashMessages() {
  $('#flash').animate({"top": "+=50px"}, 200, function(){
    setTimeout(hideFlashMessages, 5200);
  });
}

//this hides the flash
function hideFlashMessages() {
  $('#flash').animate({"top": "-=50px"}, 200)
}

// Clear form
el.find('textarea').val('');
```

Or better, because `fadeOut` and `animate` all uses queue, just use `delay` to set timeout

```js
var el = $('#new_message'); //grab the form

// this makes the message form disappear
$('#message_pad').animate({'top':'-300px'},500,function(){
  $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    // Clear form
    el.find('textarea').val('');

    //this refreshes the flash partial
    flash = $('#flash');
    flash.html('<%= escape_javascript render( :partial => 'layouts/flash' ) %>');
    flash.delay(800).animate({"top": "+=50px"}, 200);
    flash.delay(5200).animate({"top": "-=50px"}, 200);
  });
});
```